# Updating displayed images in ArrayList on button press

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm currently working on a high card game in Java.

I have a JavaFX UI with a play, deal and exit button.
I create 4 players, record the highest number and display the cards in the UI.
Now each time the deal button pressed, 4 cards are dealt out and the winner of the current round is shown.

Now here is my question: How do I link my images to an ArrayList so that the displayed cards are updated when a button is pressed? I know I have to add event handlers to the buttons, but I don't know how to link images to an ArrayList so that they change every time when a button is pressed.

The main UI:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene1, scene2, scene3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        // Root node

        Group root = new Group();

//Button 1
        Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the JavaFx Card Game!");
        label1.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        label1.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman",
                FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 200));
        label1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Blue;");
        Button button1 = new Button("Click here to Start the Game");
        button1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue;");
        label1.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman",
                FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 20));
        button1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

        //Layout 1 - children laid out in vertical column
        HBox layout1 = new HBox(20);
         layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
       // layout1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-background-color: Blue;");
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 500, 500);


//Button 2
        Button button2 = new Button("Go Back to Main page");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));
        button2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
//Button 3
        Button button3 = new Button("Play");
        button3.setStyle("-fx-border-color:orange;");
        button3.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene3));

//Button 4
        Button button4 = new Button("Deal");
        button4.setStyle("-fx-border-color:yellow;");
//Button 5
        Button button5 = new Button("Exit");
        button5.setStyle("-fx-border-color:pink");

        // creating cards box

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10,50,200, 300);

        rectangle.setArcHeight(15);
        rectangle.setArcWidth(15);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(20,200,200, 300);

        rectangle2.setArcHeight(15);
        rectangle2.setArcWidth(15);
        rectangle2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle2.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle(10,50,200, 300);

        rectangle3.setArcHeight(15);
        rectangle3.setArcWidth(15);
        rectangle3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle3.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        Rectangle rectangle4 = new Rectangle(20,200,200, 300);

        rectangle4.setArcHeight(15);
        rectangle4.setArcWidth(15);
        rectangle4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle4.setFill(Color.AQUA);



//Layout 2
        HBox layout2 = new HBox();
        layout2.setPadding(new Insets(100, 100, 100, 100));
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(button2, button3, button4, button5);
        layout2.setSpacing(25);
        layout2.setLayoutX(200);
        layout2.setLayoutY(350);



// Layout 3
        HBox layout3 = new HBox();
        layout3.setPadding(new Insets(100, 100, 100, 100));
        layout3.setSpacing(25);
        layout3.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, rectangle2, rectangle3, rectangle4);

        // adding layout 3 and layout 2
        root.getChildren().addAll(layout3, layout2);

        scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 300);

//Display scene 1 at first
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("Card Game");
        window.show();

// Max the window
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());

        primaryStage.show();

        // Back ground Image for Layer 1
        BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/LAXk1jw.png",1000,1000,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
//then you set to your node
        layout1.setBackground(new Background(myBI));


    }



}
```

The card class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {
    String finalCard = "";
     int suit, number;
    static String [] suits = {"Heart" , "Diamond" , "Spade" , "Club"}; //suits
    static String [] numbers = { "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King" , "Ace" }; //card values
    String card = "";
    public Card() {

    }
     public Card(int suits, int numbers)
        {
            suit = suits; 
            number = numbers;
        }
     public int getSuit()
     {
       return suit;
     }   


    public String toString()
        {
            String finalCard = numbers[number] + " of " + suits[suit];
            return finalCard;        
        }
    }
```

And the deck class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class FullDeck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();//card array list

        public FullDeck()
        {   
            for(int a =0; a<=3; a++) //loops through suits
            {
                for(int b =0; b<=12;b++) //loops through values
                {
                    cards.add(new Card(a,b)); //creates adds cards to list
                }

            }

        }

        public Card drawRandomCard()
        {
            Random generator = new Random(); //picks random card
            int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
            return cards.remove(index); //removes card from list
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String result = "Cards remaining in deck: " + cards; //not currently used
            return result;
        }    
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link the image to the ArrayList. You link it to the Card. Simply create a reference to the image in your Card class. Iterate through the cards and load the images one by one.

Regarding your code, I rather suggest that instead of using Random all the time you invoke a [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) on the cards. Besides of that I'd create enums for suit and rank. If you wish you could take a look at some [example code](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/e00f7e97852c9113877b).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the displayed images when a button is pressed, right?

It sounds like you expect `ArrayList` to do some magic.
I'm not even sure `ArrayList` is what you want, and I don't know why you would think so.

But here's how it works:

You need to have the images in some form somewhere. The JavFX way of doing this would be an array of [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).
Those you can add to and remove from any `Parent` how you like (just note that you can't draw the same `ImageView` twice, but that case shouldn't occur in your card game).
And you need to add event handlers to your buttons to do exactly that: add and remove the images (via `parent.getChildren().add()`/`parent.getChildren().remove()`).

---

Original answer (should work too, but is not "the JavaFX way"):

You need to have the images in some form somewhere. The most straightforward way is probably an array of `Image`.
Then you need a place to draw your images somewhere. Again, the most straightforward way is probably to add as many [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) to your `HBox` as you need to draw cards.
And then you need to add event handlers to your buttons to update those canvases. After the current cards have changed, for each visible card you need to get the right image from your `Image` array and draw it on the [`GraphicsContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) of the right canvas using `canvas`[`.getGraphicsContext2D()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html#getGraphicsContext2D--)[`.drawImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-).

Comment: That's not how you do a card game in JavaFX. You use nodes like ImageView to display the cards. You don't draw directly on a Canvas.